# HTML form with javascript conditional field and redirection

Tags: javascript, forms, conditional-statements

I am building a form allowing people to download a PDF upon submission.

Problem is that I am not able to include a conditional redirection on the form.
Would you mind having a look at the code?

JS

```
function OnSubmitForm() {
    if (document.download.Resource[doc1].checked == true) {
        document.download.action = "url1";
    } else if (document.download.Resource[doc2].checked == true) {
        document.download.action = "url2";
    } else if (document.download.Resource[doc2].checked == true) {
        document.download.action = "url3";
    }
    return true;
}
```

HTML

```
<p><strong>To download this article, please, complete the fields below</strong>

    <p>Resource:</p>
    <table width="100px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Doc1</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="Resource" value="doc1" name="Resource" type="radio" validatethis="radio" checked="true">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doc2</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="Resource" value="doc2" name="Resource" type="radio" validatethis="radio">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doc3</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="Resource" value="doc3" name="Resource" type="radio" validatethis="radio">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
                <input value="Submit" type="submit">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0z8hu7tv/3/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that what you want, cannot be done with only html or css. You will need PHP (submitting the form) or jquery (showing the links) for it.

Comment: Both of your questions are possible, however, point #2 is not something that would be accomplished with CSS. I highly recommend you look into some programming tutorials, as this is a fairly easy task

Comment: You have already something wrong on your code the two radio buttons should have the same name so you can select one at a time or they can be checked togeteher, take a look here:

`<input type="radio" name="audit" value="yes" checked>Yes
<input type="radio" name="audit" value="no">No</label>`

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!
Since I am not really skilled (not at all actually) with that type of language, I have been looking around.
Is Jquery a good option in this case? I was thinking of using some of resources from http://www.alpacajs.org/examples/components/dependency/conditional-field.html

Or would you have better site to suggest?
Is it something difficult to implement myself otherwise?

And finally, what about the "1." of my question?

Thanks so much

Comment: I have changed slightly what I need to do on the form to something simpler. However, I still can't get this to work..
Mind having a look at the edited question?
Thanks!